# A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have my flutter App integrated with firebase, everything was fine but when I migrated firebase project to client firebase console, added his google services file, changed DefaultFirebaseOption.currentplatform file credentials but I got error whenever I try to run my app.
My main method looks like this:

```js
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();  
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

The error is:

> E/flutter (28330): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists.

I searched here and found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331011/firebase-app-named-default-already-exists-app-duplicate-app) from here and updated my main method like this:

```js
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   if (Firebase.apps.isNotEmpty) {
     await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
   }else{
     Firebase.app()
   }
  //await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();  
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

but this time I got no error but my app UI is not showing, I just see black screen.
I have been trying to solve this from 4 to 5 hours but found no solution.any Help will highly be appreciated.

> Update
> I provide name parameter in both of the scenrios and my app worked fine for first time i install, but when i retart or close app and re run it, I got same error as mentioned in above cases.

Comment: I think the condition should be different like: 
```
if(Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
    }
```

Comment: Finally, Did you resolve the issue? @K_Chandio

Answer (score 59):

I had similar issue when create firebase app by flavors using flutterfire CLI. I realized that flutterfire create apps with same name in different projects.
Then I tried 2 ways and it works.

- 1st: manually change app name in each firebase project.
- 2nd: add param name when initialize such as in main_dev.dart

  ```
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
   name: "dev project",
   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  ```

Comment: it worked with adding name

Comment: work like magic!

Comment: just adding name works. I have added the firebase project name.

Comment: You make my day.

Comment: life saver command

Comment: This might resolve the error but can cause other problems. The error mentioned by the OP usually presents when there is a mismatch between native configuration (GoogleService-Info.plist google-services.json) and flutter configuration (DefaultFirebaseOptions.dart). If you specify a name when initialising Firebase in Flutter, you'll end up with two FirebaseApp initialised (one from native config named DEFAULT and another from flutter initialisation with the name you provided)

Answer (score 23):

Adding a *name* param is to avoid the issue but does not fix the real issue.

In my case (Flutter), I've been using *firebase_options.dart* generated file while there were still some old *google-services.json* files inside each android flavor directories

```
android/app/src/<flavor>/google-services.json
```

and the same on ios:

```
ios/Runner/<flavor>/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

Deleting those old files solve the issue.

Make a 'Flutter clean' after and delete manually android/build if not deleted

Comment: what are flavour directories? I'm having this problem as well but I only have one copy of the files you mentioned

Comment: @NathanTew See this article for flavors, which are for different settings per environment: https://kmtsandeepanie.medium.com/set-up-multiple-firebase-environments-in-flutter-9f88bc284454

Comment: @NathanTew if you don't have any flavours setup, you can just delete the single files.

Comment: Out of interest, how to you the set the firebase options to work with product flavors?

Comment: @James Have a look at this https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-flavors-for-firebase-apps/

Comment: I still needed a `flutter pub get` and a `flutterfire configure` after deleting, which created an up-to-date **GoogleService-Info.plist**.

Answer (score 15):

Got this error after fumbling with firebase projects and upgrading packages.

Fixed by

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

then build the project again.

I have apps with same name in different projects, this doesn't seem to cause the error.

Comment: This solve my issue. I am changing fiebase project, cleaning it solve the duplicate issue.

Comment: I like how almost every flutter issue ```flutter clean``` and pub get is almost always the fix lol

Answer (score 11):

this might happen with outdated google-services file or switching from project to another with flutter fire tool

`android/app/src/<flavor>/google-services.json`

`ios/Runner/<flavor>/GoogleService-Info.plist`

`lib/firebase_options.dart`

then write these commands

1- `flutter clean`

2- then with [flutterfire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/) cli installed `flutterfire configure`

3- `flutter pub get`
this should fix the issue

c**hanging the name with name in `await Firebase.initializeApp(.....` will cause problems with firebase services**

Comment: I had the error on mac with the ios simulator. The GoogleService-Info.plist was outdated. I changed to my prod firebase project with flutterfire configure --project myfirebaseprojectname, but this cmd did not touch the GoogleService-Info.plist for ios, therefore I just deleted this file and then ran the above flutterfire configure command and then it created (among others) the correct file for ios.

Comment: I deleted the two google service files and went through the clean, configure and pub get commands and everything worked finally.

Answer (score 3):

In my case incorrect GoogleService-Info.plist was linked in xCode from downloads folder. But correct was in Runner folder, so i thought that its ok. So check in `Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources` that GoogleService-Info.plist exists and path is correct.

Comment: For me too, I had a GoogleService-Info.plist in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        );
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already added the **GoogleService-Info** in your **ios/Runner** and you were using flutter fire cli just remove this line :

Before:

```dart
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
       // remove this
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

After:

```dart
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Comment: This worked well. As of 01/2023 when running `flutterfire configure` it generated the GoogleService-Info.plist, firebase_app_id_file.json, and firebase_options.dart

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Seb's answer, giving a name to `Firebase.initializeApp` is a workaround and not a definitive fix.

In my case, it was sligthly different (hope this can help others), because I had FCM on my app for several years (before `flutterfire configure` was out), and when I "migrated" by using the new fluttefire configuration, it did generate a *`firebase_options.dart`* with bunch of options here.

For some reason I can't explain, the `apiKey` for iOS set in the **FirebaseOptions** for *ios* was incorrect.

Check out in the Google Cloud Console, look for **Credentials** (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and take a look at auto-generated keys. Take the value from there to fix the `apiKey` setting.

That was enough for fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1)
flutter clean &
flutter pub get

2)
Deleting google-services.json and download new google-services.json from firebase.
If you are using cli run `fluttefire configure`one more.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using flutterfire you should match FirebaseOptions and google-services.json

firebase_options.dart

```
static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'your_api_ky',
    appId: 'your_api_id',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
    projectId: '...',
    storageBucket: '...',
  );
```

google-services.json

```
"project_info": {
    "project_number": "...",
    "project_id": "...",
    "storage_bucket": "..."
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "your_api_id",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.app_your"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just deleted the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and `firebase_app_id_file.json` in the `ios` folder and ran the Flutter Firebase CLI again and it got fixed