# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.default.apps')

Tags: firebase, react-native

this is my code. I am new to react native and trying to make a firebase authanticator using firebase in expo. please hell me with this error. I am facing similar issue for other things related to firebase also.

````js
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "removed",
  authDomain: "removed",
  databaseURL: "removed",
  projectId: "removed",
  storageBucket: "removed",
  messagingSenderId: "removed",
  appId: "removed"
};

// Initialize Firebase
let app;
if(firebase.apps.length === 0){
    app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}else{
    app = firebase.app()
}

const auth = firebase.auth
export { auth };```
````

Comment: Are you following instructions for react-native? It looks like you have a web app setup.

Comment: I am getting the same error

Comment: I am also getting the same error can someone solve this please

Comment: Hi, please how did you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

see [How to check if a Firebase App is already initialized on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652328/how-to-check-if-a-firebase-app-is-already-initialized-on-android)

and switch to s/t like

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
```