# How to initialize firebase in firebase version 9 (firebase v9)?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I used to initialize my firebase app using this method -

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
};

export default function initFirebase() {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
}
```

I am upgrading my firebase version to 9 and I need a way to initialize my app using es modules.

I tried this -

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";

const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
};

export default function initFirebase() {
    getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(config) : getApp();
}
```

But I am getting this error -

FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use `initializeApp`?

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
};

export const app = initializeApp(config);
```

Do you really need your custom `initFirebase()` function?

Comment: Do I have to import the app variable somewhere to initialize firebase or can I leave it as it is?

Comment: I believe you do not need to import app anywhere. In the same file you can initialize auth, firestore and other firebase services - and this is what you usually need to import somewhere.

Comment: Why is it safe to have an API key in NEXT_PUBLIC? Won't these variables be exposed to end users?